# extracting the string using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have the following text coming from a text file:

```
This is a Test, Section test TS 544 Ord 0 (1246788-5)   [2]
This is a Test2, Section test TS 544 Ord 675 (1246788)   [3]
This is a Tes3 (345678)  
This is a Test 5 TS 544 Ord 12345
This is a Tes3 (PQ345678) 
This is a Test9 TS 544 Ord XP (A567843)
This is a test8  TS 344 Ord Z [9]
```

I want to extract The number with in the round brackets and put that in variable so I want this:

```
Var a1 =  The number within the round brackets so for e.g  1246788-5 or    345678 or PQ345678 or A567843
Var a2= I also want number in square brackets 2 or 3 or 9
Var a3 = I want to extarct all the numbers starting from TS and end at the next space so I need TS 544 ord 0, TS 544 Ord 675, TS 544 Ord 12345, TS 544 ORD XP
```

These values are coming from the text file. Can I extract these values in C# or Vb.net using regular expression.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please show the relevant part of your code? What have you tried so far? Could you also specify what should be matched between brackets... Is `"PQ345678"` a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\()([^)]*)(?=\))|(?<=\[)([^\]]*)(?=\])|(?<=TS\s)(\d+\s+\S+\s+\d+\b)
```

You can use this single regex.`group 1` will be your `var a1` and so on.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/9